# UITableView header size is changed after UISearchController closes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm initializing my UISearchController like this:

```
self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Buscar mensajes"
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
self.searchController.delegate = self
self.searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Then I add it to UITableView like this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
```

This is how it looks at beginning:

[image: Opening search]

Then when I open search bar it goes up to navigation bar as I wanted to:

[image: Cancel search]

But after cancel button is pressed, table view doesn't layout correctly:

[image: The bug]

And it is not something about offset, it is related to table view header height. Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these ticked in your settings?

[image]

Comment: No, because I'm creating UITableView programmatically as well. Do you know how to set those parameters in code? I tried automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true, edgesForExtendedLayout = .all, but nothing changed.

Comment: Think its; self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone. Let me know if that works.

Comment: No, that didn't work :( And the weird thing is that sometimes it layouts correctly after cancel tap, but most of the times it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Adjust Scoll View insets" in IB

Look like this:

[image]